# Por que usar um reducer em vez de um simples state?

Tags: react, react-hooks

O [`useReducer`](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) parece ser uma wrapper do [`useState`](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), em vez de passar um novo estado, é passado uma ação (através de uma chave/id que a identifica), no reducer, um novo estado é definido baseado na ação e algum outro parâmetro passado

State:

```js
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

const increment = () => setCounter(counter + 1);

const decrement = () => setCounter(counter - 1);
```

Reducer:

```js
const [counter, dispatch] = useReducer((counter, action) => {
  switch (action) {
    case 'increment':
      return counter + 1;
    case 'decrement':
      return counter - 1;
    default:
      return counter;
  }
}, 0);

const increment = () => dispatch('increment');

const decrement = () => dispatch('decrement');
```

O state parece ser bem mais direto, simples e limpo, então, existe alguma vantagem em usar o reducer? Algum caso em que ele é necessário ou melhor?

Answer (score 0):

Ambos são realmente bem semelhantes, e é comum a confusão. O uso de um em detrimento do outro vai depender mais do seu caso de uso. O comum da comunidade é usar o `useReducer` para estados mais complexos, segue o exemplo:

Se eu quiser incrementar, decrementar ou resetar um contador, usando `useState`, ficaria assim:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

// Incrementar
setCounter(counter + 1);

// Decrementar
setCounter(counter - 1);

// Resetar
setCounter(0);
```

É algo mais simplório e possui apenas uma forma de editar o estado. Com os `useReducer`, poderíamos ter uma função dispatch diferente para cada ação dessas, e poderíamos sempre manter uma organização maior fazendo isto, até mesmo se nosso estado escalasse, como por exemplo criando um booleano de `ativo` no estado:

```
const initialState = {count: 0, ativo: false};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    case 'reset':
      return {count: 0};
    case 'shutdown':
      return {ativo: false};
    case 'shutdown':
      return {count: 0, ativo: true};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```